# Does a non-parametric model necessarily have zero bias?

Tags: machine-learning, bias, nonparametric

For a parametric model like linear regression, the bias is often interpreted as "the parameters & architecture you chose are inappropriate for the shape of this dataset".

For (one definition of) a non-parametric model, the model is not "built on" parameters, but rather by storing a subset of the data itself [1]. The model's capacity thus is not limited by parameters, and grows with the training data.

So, does a non-parametric model necessarily have zero bias?

[1] On page 15 [of Andrew Ng's notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf).

Comment: If you use wrong feature, you would have bias whatever model you use. And if you use right feature, you would not have any bias with the parametric model.

Comment: @kevin012 Ah true, bias is a function of the choice of features as well, which is unrelated to parametric/non-parametric. Is there a quick proof of your second sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may give you an example. Let's consider two feature $X_1$ and $X_2$. The feature $X_1$ gives the unbiased model. And $X_2$ is related to the $X_1$ by the relationship:

$$X_2 = X_1 + a$$

where $a$ is constant.

Let's consider we know the true model which is given by:

$$ Y = X_1^2 + \varepsilon$$

where $\varepsilon$ is noise term with $E[\varepsilon] = 0$

So we have the unbiased model with the feature $X_1$.

But if you happen to use feature $X_2$, you would get
$$
\begin{align}
Y &= {X_2}^2 + \varepsilon\\
&=X_1^2 + 2aX_1+a^2 +\varepsilon
\end{align}
$$

The term, $ 2aX_1+a^2$ give rise to bias and the basis cannot be removed if you use only the feature $X_2$.

So if you use the wrong feature $X_2$, you will get the biased model but you can remove the bias by using the correct feature $X_1$.

---

For a non-parametric model, we may think of kNN as your model. And let's assume the true model is linear this time:

$$ Y = X_1 + \varepsilon$$

For the data generated by the linear relationship, you will get an unbiased estimation of $Y$ with kNN.

On the other hand,  if you use $X_2$ instead of $X_1$ for your model, you have

$$
\begin{align}
Y &= {X_2} + \varepsilon\\
&=X_1 + a +\varepsilon
\end{align}
$$

That is to say, you will get the biased estimation of $Y$ with bias $a$ if you use kNN with feature $X_2$.

Comment: Thanks! I understand now that a non-parametric model can have bias (through its features). Can you also explain your comment that a non-parametric model has no bias if it uses the right features?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Let me summarize your answer: bias comes from (1) your choice of features and (2) your choice of the relationship between features -> label, which is implicit in your choice of model. Non-parametric models only have bias from (1).

Comment: @kennysong If the true relationship is non-linear, and you use a linear feature, whatever model you use, you will get bias regardless of parametric/non-parametric most of cases. Non-parametric doesn't cure the wrong relationship.

Comment: And your definition of non-parametric is quite narrow. You may check this post on the definition: stats.stackexchange.com/q/137636/276972

Comment: If you use linear features, many models can still learn non-linear relationships with vanishingly small bias, no? E.g. decision trees (non-param.), kNN (non-param.), SVM with non-linear kernel (non-param.), neural networks (param.).

Comment: @kennysong I'm talking of the case you approximate the data by a wrong model. For example, if you limit the tree depth inadequately, your tree will have a bias.